# How to add prefix & attribue in json value?

Tags: json

I have a long list JSON and I want to add prefix on it but having hard time, anyway how to do it using any tool like sublime or online or javascript?

This is my sample json, the prefix is the name of my file after this json execute, so I need to add `underscore`. just like below.

before it was `"prefix": "Z99438",` then it will become `"prefix": "Z99438_",`

```
    {
        "Records": [
            {
                "prefix": "Z99438_",
                "keywords": "Lancome Nutrix Nourishing and Repairing Treatment Rich Cream 75ml",
                "limit": 1,
                "print_urls": true,
                "image_directory": "A002152"
            },
            {
                "prefix": "Z99438_",
                "keywords": "Tom Ford Black Orchid Eau de Parfum 50ml Spray",
                "limit": 1,
                "print_urls": true,
                "image_directory": "A00586"
            }
        ]
...
    }
```

also any idea how to add new attribute with same key and value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Any tool* ? Here are some examples using `jq` command line parser.

If you want to append a `_` to all `prefix`:

```
jq '.Records[].prefix |= . + "_"' file
```

If you want to append a `_` to only `prefix` that have value `Z99438`:

```
jq '.Records |= map(select(.prefix == "Z99438").prefix |= . + "_")' file
```